# Using linq to separate strings where the special character is

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I've got a foreach loop that iterates through rows in an sql table.
One of the columns, named 'UserName', lists users and their location separated by '#'.

Example:

| Id | UserName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Room1 # John Smith |
| 2 | Room2 # Jane Doe |

I'm trying to get the location and the name into separate variables while excluding the #.
I'm certain this can be done with linq, but I'm having no success.

Any Help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Why Linq? String.Split will separate the string and create an array with the two values.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? how are you mapping sql data to object?

Comment: @Steve I've tried: UserName.Split('#').Where(z => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(z)). I'm just struggling to figure out how to put them both into separate variables.

Comment: That line of code returns an array of strings.  If it is formatted as the table suggests then the variable you assign it to [0] will be the location and [1] will be the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Entity Framework it could be something like this

```
public Users
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public UserViewModel 
{
   public string Room {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}

var users = dbContext.Users.Select(user => new UserViewModel {
   Room = user.UserName.Split(new char[] { '#' }).First(),
   Name = user.UserName.Split(new char[] { '#' }).Last()
}).ToLIst();
```

Comment: Just note that if you do not trim that string you will have leading or ending white space according to your data example

Comment: @ChrisBartlett yes, you're absolutely right. `Trim()` should be applied to both `Room` and `Name` like this `Room = user.UserName.Split(new char[] { '#' }).First().Trim()`